# How to test function calling explicitly using React testing and jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Am having component like below

```
Class A extends Component {
    function1() { 
      this.func2
    }

    func2() {
      // returns some value
    }
    render() { 
       return() {
         <div> {this.function1}
        }
     }
 }
```

How can I call directly function1 in react testing, need to test whether func2 called. Previously in enzyme used instance.

Comment: You don't. Don't test implementation details, test _behaviour_.

Comment: But I need to write test case for it as it is available in enzyme

Comment: You don't "need" to call the method directly. Just because Enzyme let you do it doesn't make it a good idea (one of the reasons it's become much less popular). It looks like the method returns content that gets rendered when the component is, so _assert on the rendered content_ not the method call.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you need to do these things:

1. Calling `function1()` directly in the test without using Enzyme
2. Need to test whether `func2()` was called, while calling `function1()`

Here is what you can do to achieve the same in your Jest testing file for your component. In order to completely use Jest and React only, some alternatives would be:

1. Using [React Test Utils](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html) to render the component
2. Creating an instance, and then calling the function

```js
test('func2 is called when function1 is called', () => {
  const mockFunc2 = jest.fn();
  const myComponent = ReactTestUtils.createRenderer().render(<A />);
  const instance = myComponent.getInstance();
  
  // Replace the implementation of func2 with our mock
  instance.func2 = mockFunc2;
  
  // Call function1
  instance.function1();
  
  // Expect func2 to have been called
  expect(mockFunc2).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

**Additionally:**

1. You can use `act()` from the same module `react-dom/test-utils`, and wrap your rendering inside it to prepare a component for assertions, and performing updates. This makes your test run closer to how React works in the browser.

```js
  import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

  let myComponent;

  // Test first render and componentDidMount
  act(() => {
    myComponent = ReactTestUtils.createRenderer().render(<A />);
  });
```

2. You can also read about [mock functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions) to understand the concept in detail.

Comment: Shallow is from enzyme I don't want to use it

Comment: Answer edited. I have used `render()`, in place of `shallow` now. Please take a look @roy

Comment: I think find is also from enzyme

Comment: I have edited my answer again, and used `ReactTestUtils`, which you can import from `react-dom/test-utils`, and try doing the test @roy

Comment: OK need to test thanks will give up vote if it works

Comment: Will it work for functional component based on documentation it works for only class component

Comment: It's showing issue cannot read property create of undefined